# Is it correct to say "I had my face put on a mask"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

**I cut my hair**: I cut it by myself

**I had my hair cut**: Someone cut my hair

**I put a mask on my face**: I did it myself

**I had my face put on a mask**: Someone did it to me.

Is it correct to say "**I had my face put on a mask**"?

For example, "**some Covid patients have their faces put on masks to breathe in oxygen**"?

Comment: Tom, when is your challenge to the language going to be over? "I had my face put on a mask." means: A printer or graphic designer had a picture of me and printed it on a mask. Your Covid example does not work.

Comment: Oh, I thought it meant that I told my face to put on a mask, and it did. ;)

Comment: @gotube: By which logic you should interpret *I had my hair cut* as meaning that you instructed your hair to do some cutting.

Comment: @gotube Funny is good but not with those who are funnier (OP).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't beat yourself up over it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  You have missed the passive nature of "I had my hair cut".

By analogy the "mask" is the object of put, in the way that "hair" is the object of "cut".

So with this passive participle you get

> I had a mask put on my face.

The word "face" is not the object of the verb put, so it doesn't become a subject in a passive construction.

In full that would be

> Some COVID patients have masks put on their faces to breathe in oxygen.

Comment: This OP always does the same thing. And sometimes is mistaken in the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If your face has hands and it can pick up the mask and wear it, then you can say **I had my face put on a mask**.

Or like @lambie said, if a graphic designer copied a picture of you onto a mask then you can say **I had my face put on a mask**.

Comment: Note the two distinct meanings of "put on" used in the two sentences.